# Change Height of Keyboard Extension Dynamically

Tags: swift, keyboard, constraints, ios9

I have a keyboard extension which starts with a height constant of 280. I give it the height constraint with the code below. I call this in viewWillAppear.

```
    func normalHeight() {
    constant = 280
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0) {
        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 0.0, constant: self.constant)
        heightConstraint.priority = self.normalHeightPriority
        self.view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
    }
    self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    self.view.setNeedsDisplay()

}
```

I also animate an increase in the height constraint with the code below which also works. The height increases.

```
    func extendedHeight() {
    constant = 400
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0) { 
        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 0.0, constant: self.constant)
        heightConstraint.priority = self.extendedHeightPriority
        self.view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
    }
    self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

To revert the height, I call normalHeight() again from a button and this does not work. I thought maybe the priorities were the problem because the extendeHeight constraint has a 1000 priority and the normalHeight constraint has a 999 priority.
So I flip the priorities when the functions are called like below. Still no dice.

```
    func normalHeight() {
    constant = 280
    normalPriority = 1000
    extendedPriority = 999
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0) {
        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 0.0, constant: self.constant)
        heightConstraint.priority = self.normalPriority
        self.view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
    }
    print("Normal Height Called")
    self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    self.view.setNeedsDisplay()

}
```

and on the extended priority like so

```
    func extendedHeight() {
    constant = 400
    extendedPriority = 1000
    normalPriority = 999
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0) {
        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 0.0, constant: self.constant)
        heightConstraint.priority = self.extendedPriority
        self.view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
    }
    self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

I will appreciate any help and insight into why this does not work. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution.
I added two height constraints to the view and gave them priorities of high and low.
The constraint priorities should be high and low priority which is 750 and 250 respectively instead of 1000 and 999 I was using earlier

Now when I want to change the height I flip the priorities of the two installed constraints.

```
    func initialHeight() {
    AConstant = 280
    BConstant = 400
    self.aheightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 0.0, constant: self.AConstant)
    self.aheightConstraint!.priority = 750
    self.view.addConstraint(self.aheightConstraint!)

    self.bheightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 0.0, constant: self.BConstant)
    self.bheightConstraint.priority = 250
    self.view.addConstraint(bheightConstraint)

    self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
```

For the extended height I call

```
 func extendedHeight() {
    bheightConstraint.priority = 750
    aheightConstraint.priority = 250
    view.setNeedsLayout()

}
```

and to revert to normal height I call

```
    func normalHeight() {
    bheightConstraint.priority = 250
    aheightConstraint.priority = 750
    view.setNeedsLayout()
}
```